# Unable to remove root password for Ubuntu Bionic OS

Tags: 18.04, ssh, password, root

I have a system with Linux Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver) and one user account (root). I can access the system either with a console or an Ethernet connection. Over a console, I have no problem at all and I just need to type root to log in. However, when I try to access through SSH, the system keeps asking for a password even though the root account is passwordless. I executed the following commands to give root user access without a password but it did not help.

```
sudo sed -i 's/#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo service ssh restart
```

So I gave the root user a password using `passwd` command and now I can access my system through SSH.

Now, I am trying to remove the root password to reset the system to its original state. So I executed `passwd -d root` which returned `passwd: password expiry information changed.`
However, when I try to login again using the console the system asks for both user name and the password of the root account.

I searched on the Internet and it seems just executing `passwd -d root` is sufficient to make the password empty. So I created a temporary user account with sudo access. Using this account, I tried to remove the root password, but again it did not work i.e. the system keeps asking for the root password and without it, I cannot log in.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not able to do so" - what happens, exactly? Does the `passwd -d root` command return an error? Does the shadow file not change? Are you running the command from an actual root login, or using one of your sudoers?

Comment: @guiverc I am using Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, sorry it was a typo

Comment: Why would you _ever_ want to allow root to ssh into a system connected to the internet? That is just asking for trouble. Why not use the normal approach of having a regular, non-root user who can ssh and then you can become root with `sudo -i` after logging in?

Comment: @steeldriver `passwd` does not return any error but it does not have any effect on the root account. I am still prompted to enter the password.
I am executing the command from the actual root login and I tried to change it from the other temporary sudoer account as I mentioned but still, I am always prompted to enter the password.

Comment: "still prompted" doesn't mean the password wasn't deleted. SSH will still try any available authentication methods.

Comment: @steeldriver I cannot log in to the system using the console without entering a password which was not the case at the beginning.